# How to edit email templates without the mail editor plugin?

Tags: email, drupal, templates, drupal-modules

I've installed the mail editor module for drupal in order to edit the templates for emails that my site sends out and I get this message after enabling the module: "This version is incompatible with the 6.16 version of Drupal core." How do I work around that? Do I just keep trying older versions of the plugin or is there another plugin I can use instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you downloaded the 5.x version of Mail Editor, or a really outdated version of the 6.x branch. I downloaded the [Dev release](http://drupal.org/node/277614) (the only 6.x release available): it enables fine, and there's nothing in the code to restrict minor version numbers.

Out of curiosity, I don't see anything in Mail Editor that core's User settings page (admin/user/settings) doesn't do. Is there something more to it?

Comment: Yes, there are many more email templates you can edit with the Mail Editor. Especially if you've installed the subscriptions module